# Add illuminate/database dependency with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Hey Guys trying to add illuminate/database dependence to my project but i get an error. heres what i did and get

```
C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxxx>php composer.phar require illuminate/database
Using version ^5.1 for illuminate/database ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- illuminate/database v5.1.1 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiabl
e by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22,v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- illuminate/database v5.1.13 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- illuminate/database v5.1.16 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- illuminate/database v5.1.2 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- illuminate/database v5.1.20 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- illuminate/database v5.1.22 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- illuminate/database v5.1.6 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- illuminate/database v5.1.8 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- illuminate/support v5.1.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- illuminate/support v5.1.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- illuminate/support v5.1.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- illuminate/support v5.1.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- illuminate/support v5.1.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- illuminate/support v5.1.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- illuminate/support v5.1.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- illuminate/support v5.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for illuminate/database ^5.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: I'm sure the people around here would like to take a look at the contents of your composer.json file.

Comment: my composer.json {
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^2.6",
        "slim/views": "^0.1.3",
        "twig/twig": "^1.23",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
        "hassankhan/config": "^0.8.2"
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty much obvious that you need to install the mbstring extention. Just go to your php.ini and uncomment the

`extension=php_mbstring.dll`

line.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get in the composer now ?

Answer (score 0):

Your command line version of PHP is missing the mbstring extension.

Run `php -i` to get the info data. Find the part that tells you which `php.ini` file has been used. Edit this file to add the extension. Run the composer command again. It should work.

Note that the CLI PHP usually uses a different INI file than PHP of the webserver. Additionally, CLI PHP need not to be restarted, because it isn't part of a constantly running process.

Example from my machine (excerpt):

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have mentioned 5.1.* for version (for illuminate) in your composer.json making it ambiguous.  You need to specify a particular version like for e.g. 5.1.16 to remove the ambiguity in the version. Also `extension=php_mbstring.dll` your extension mbstring is missing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: here is my composer.json **{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^2.6",
        "slim/views": "^0.1.3",
        "twig/twig": "^1.23",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
        "hassankhan/config": "^0.8.2"
    }
}
 **

Comment: @Sam'sOnWandah remove all version and type `*` instead for.e.g.   `"slim/views": "*"`. By this way it will take the latest version for all by default,

Comment: It is a very bad idea to simply use `*` as a version requirement. And it is wrong to specify an explicit version either, as suggested in your answer. The version is ambigous for a reason: To allow updates being installed later, and allow previous versions to be installed in case the current platform does not support the latest version fully.

Comment: @Sven dully noted but is there an answer in your comment as your statement contradicts itself. not to use * or neither a specific version. What to do then ?! please clarify

Comment: @Sam'sOnWandah did it get solved or you facing the same issue ?

Comment: @user1519817: Using `*` would mean "anything" - but every major version should be assumed to be incompatible with previous versions, so how would you be able to use that? Minor versions usually add new features, so what if you need a feature that isn't present in an earlier version? On the other hand, if you specify an explicit version, you will exactly get that version - what about updating then? It works better than `*` (you get exactly what you specify), but will also lead to problems due to the inflexibility to choose from a range of matching versions, especially when adding stuff later.